# How to run step function workflow after lambda is called?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-step-functions

I am trying to setup a step functions workflow in my serverless app. What I want to happen is that when the UserPost endpoint is called it creates the user and proceeds to run through the step functions after. Currently I have this flow in my serverless.yml

```js
serverless.yml

functions:
  UserPost:
    handler: handlers/user/post.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /user
          method: post
          cors: true

  UserProcessingStepOne:
    handler: handlers/user/processing/step.one.handler
  UserProcessingStepTwo:
    handler: handlers/user/processing/step.two.handler
  UserProcessingStepThree:
    handler: handlers/user/processing/step.three.handler
  UserProcessingStepFour:
    handler: handlers/user/processing/step.four.handler
  UserProcessingStepFive:
    handler: handlers/user/processing/step.five.handler

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    UserPostStateMachine:
      definition:
        Comment: "Create And Process User Workflow"
        StartAt: UserPost
        States:
          UserPost:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-UserPost"
            Next: UserProcessingStepOne
          UserProcessingStepOne:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-UserProcessingStepOne"
            Next: UserProcessingStepTwo
          UserProcessingStepTwo:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-UserProcessingStepTwo"
            Next: UserProcessingStepThree
          UserProcessingStepThree:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-UserProcessingStepThree"
            Next: UserProcessingStepFour
          UserProcessingStepFour:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-UserProcessingStepFour"
            Next: UserProcessingStepFive
          UserProcessingStepFive:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-UserProcessingStepFive"
            End: true
```

Now in each of the processing files I have a console log that is something like this:

```js
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false

  console.log("Processing Step One: Process Profile")
}
```

Now when send data as a POST request to my /user endpoint it is working properly. But, I do not see any of the step functions being executed afterwards. Is there something I am missing?